# Questions with java socket

Tags: java, sockets

In java, I can write code like this:

```
 ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1111);
 Socket s = ss.accept();
 // here s.getLocalPort() is 1111
 ss.close();
 // here this is ok even s is still connected with a client.
 ss = new ServerSocket(s.getLocalPort());
```

on client side:

```
Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 1111);
// this line will throw an exception. 
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(s.getLocalPort());
```

What I don't understand is the last line of the above two pieces of code seems no difference, why does it work differently? any info is highly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you closed the socket, in the second you didn't, so the port is still occupied.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, in the first case, I just closed the server socket "ss", but the socket "s" is still alive

Comment: Correct, yet you don't listen to this port for new connections anymore, only communicate with the already established connections.

Comment: yes, that is my question, see the second case, there is no socket listening on the port s.getLocalPort(), but why cannot I create a socket listening on it?